# How to align this ratio?

Tags: formatting

I'm looking for a neat expression for `$\frac{ \partial A^{-1}}{\partial \alpha}$`. I want it to look like `$\frac{\partial A }{\partial \alpha}$`(the numerator and denominator to align). Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this (`\mathrlap` requires `mathtools`)?

```
\[ \frac{ \partial A^{\mathrlap{-1}}}{\partial \alpha}\enspace \neq \frac{\partial A }{\partial \alpha} \]%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly like you've written.